# How to make an algorithm repeat itself in python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x

i am trying to make the simplest algorithm i could make , the problem is i can't make the algorithm repeat it self, this is my code :

```
x=5
y=int(input('GUESS the number: '))
if y==x:
 print('you win! ')
elif y<x:
 print('x is lower than',y)
elif y>x:
 print('x is higher than',y)
```

As you can see after executing the program , It will ask you about the number , after that it will tell you if it's correct/higher/lower , the problem is when it says the number is lower/higher, the program will end , I want the a

Comment: Look at a basic Python tutorial. The word you're looking for is "loop".

Comment: You can use a `while` or `for` control statement

https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming

Comment: actually i know how to make a loop , But what type of loop  ?

Comment: and please provide me with an example or an edit , Thanks.

Comment: You want the program to run "**while** you have not input the correct solution"

Comment: Thank you guys the problem is solved,I know the basic functions but this is the first time  i program something , Thank for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a while loop:

```
y=None
x=5
while x != y:
    y=int(input('GUESS the number: '))
    if y==x:
        print('you win! ')
    elif y<x:
        print('x is higher than',y)
    elif y>x:
        print('x is lower than',y)
```

Comment: Where is `'x is higher than y'`? (Not your fault, typo in the question)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    while 1:
        pass  # your code here

if __name__ = "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This doesn't terminate at the end of the game.  If "your code' contains an appropriate test and **break** statement, this becomes a valid approach.